# Fill color in a region

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to fill gray color to the left of the curve. Can anyone give some hints? Thanks!

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}

   \begin{scope}[shift={(0,0)}]

  \draw [opacity=1, very thick, draw=red!50!black](2.4,4.5) {ellipse (2cm and 1cm)}; 

  \draw [very thick]  (2.6,5.5) parabola bend (3.4,4.6) (4,3.9);
  
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just clip with your ellipse and fill an accurate region. Here's a very rough (but working) example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw [opacity=1, very thick, draw=red!50!black](2.4,4.5) {ellipse (2cm and 1cm)}; 
        
        \draw [very thick]  (2.6,5.5) parabola bend (3.4,4.6) (4,3.9);
        
        % Here just to see the region filled        
        \draw[densely dashed,orange] (2.6,5.5) parabola bend (3.4,4.6) (4,3.9) --++ (0,-1) --++ (-4,0) --++ (0,3) -|  cycle;
        
        \clip (2.4,4.5) {ellipse (2cm and 1cm)};
        \fill[blue,opacity=0.5] (2.6,5.5) parabola bend (3.4,4.6) (4,3.9) --++ (0,-1) --++ (-4,0) --++ (0,3) -| cycle;
          
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Fill a region]

**EXPLANATION:**
Below, you will see in dashed orange the region I filled.

[image: explanation]

Comment: Great! It indeed works! Thanks!